# Excel cum sum problems when based on criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I am asking excel to cum sum cells from column BO where the corresponding cells in column C are equal to their column c predecessors, or otherwise enter the value from C where C changes from its predecessor.  Won't seem to sum.  BP11 should be 17.  Help?

[image: snap]

As shown simple formula

Comment: I think you need `=IF(C10=C11,SUM(BP10,BO11),BO11)`  (refer to column BP the row prior to your formula cell)

Comment: Try: `=SUMIF(C$2:C2,C2,BO$2:BO2)`

Comment: Your formula in `BP11` is not working because the formula you have applied in cell `BP2` is `=IF(C1=C2,SUM(BO1,BO2),BO2)` so when it comes down to cell `BP11` it checks whether `C10=C11` which is but the value for `C10` is `0` while for `C11` is `1` and hence why it returns `1` but it returns correct for `BP10` instead of doing in this manner use the running `SUMIF()` as shown in answer!

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUMIFS()` or `SUMIF()` function, you don't need an `IF()` here:

[image]

---

```
=SUMIF(C$2:C2,C2,BO$2:BO2)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

### Running Sum Only If Consecutive

**Basic**

... as suggested by **P.b**

```
=IF(C1=C2,SUM(BP1,BO2),BO2)
```

**Spilling**

```
=LET(ldata,C2:C11,vData,BO2:BO11,
    ltf,ldata=VSTACK(INDEX(ldata,1),DROP(ldata,-1)),
    SCAN(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(ltf)),LAMBDA(sr,r,
        IF(INDEX(ltf,r),sr+INDEX(vData,r),INDEX(vData,r)))))
```

**Excel Table**

```
=LET(rd,ROW()-ROW(Table1[#Headers])-1,
    IF(rd=0,[@Col2],IF([@Col1]=INDEX([Col1],rd),
        INDEX([Col3],rd)+[@Col2],[@Col2])))
```

[image]